# Remove duplicates from the same line in a file

Tags: shell

How do I remove below duplicates from the same line in a file? I need the duplicates removed including semicolon.

For example from the below output of a file I need only "dg01.server.wmq.host=jms1001-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com" similarly other lines of the file.

```
dg01.server.wmq.host=jms1001-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1001-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg02.server.wmq.host=jms1002-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1002-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg03.server.wmq.host=jms1003-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1003-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg04.server.wmq.host=jms1004-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1004-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg05.server.wmq.host=jms1005-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1005-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg06.server.wmq.host=jms1006-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1006-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg07.server.wmq.host=jms1007-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1007-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg08.server.wmq.host=jms1008-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1008-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg09.server.wmq.host=jms1009-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1009-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg10.server.wmq.host=jms1010-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1010-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg11.server.wmq.host=jms1011-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1011-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg12.server.wmq.host=jms1012-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1012-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg13.server.wmq.host=jms1013-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1013-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg14.server.wmq.host=jms1014-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1014-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg15.server.wmq.host=jms1015-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1015-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg16.server.wmq.host=jms1001-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1001-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg17.server.wmq.host=jms1002-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1002-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg18.server.wmq.host=jms1003-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1003-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg19.server.wmq.host=jms1004-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1004-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg20.server.wmq.host=jms1005-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1005-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg21.server.wmq.host=jms1006-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1006-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg22.server.wmq.host=jms1007-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1007-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg23.server.wmq.host=jms1008-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1008-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg24.server.wmq.host=jms1009-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1009-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg25.server.wmq.host=jms1010-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1010-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg26.server.wmq.host=jms1011-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1011-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg27.server.wmq.host=jms1012-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1012-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg28.server.wmq.host=jms1013-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1013-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg29.server.wmq.host=jms1014-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1014-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg30.server.wmq.host=jms1015-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1015-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg31.server.wmq.host=jms1001-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1001-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg32.server.wmq.host=jms1002-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1002-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg33.server.wmq.host=jms1003-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1003-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg34.server.wmq.host=jms1004-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1004-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg35.server.wmq.host=jms1009-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1009-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg36.server.wmq.host=jms1010-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1010-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg37.server.wmq.host=jms1011-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1011-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg38.server.wmq.host=jms1012-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1012-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg39.server.wmq.host=jms1007-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1007-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com dg40.server.wmq.host=jms1008-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1008-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com
```

Comment: You're talking about there being multiple lines but you posted a huge single line example. Please improve formatting/provide a better example so we can better understand the problem and help you.

Comment: `cut -d';' -f1 yourfile`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `dg01.server.wmq.host=jms1001-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com;jms1001-02-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com` is a line in your input file and you're only interested in the `dg01.server.wmq.host=jms1001-01-ri5.ri5.dc2.responsys.com` part *(up to, but not including, the semicolumn)* you can obtain the desired output by running:

`cat inputfile | awk -F ';' {'print $1'}`

Another way to obtain the same output, as pointed out by @Shawn, would be:

`cut -d ';' -f1 inputfile`